# Find a function that maximizes $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\rm dx$ with given constraints

Tags: integration, optimization, definite-integrals

Find a function $f(x)$ that maximizes the following integral

$$\max\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,\rm dx\quad \text{s.t.}\quad \frac{d}{dx}ln(f(x))<0$$

$f(x)$ also continues, $f:[0,1]\rightarrow R$ and we know that $f(0)=a$, $f(1)=b$ and $a>b>0$.

I think that the function f(x) that maximizes this integral in the interval $[0,1]$ with the given constraints is a linear function:

$f(x)=(b-a)x+a$

and this integral would be: $$\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}$$

Am I right?

Comment: $f(x)$ must be at least differentiable to let us state $\frac{d}{dx}\log f(x)<0$.

Comment: Is is just a way to say that $f(x)$ is positive and decreasing on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Moreover, what about: $$f(x) = b+(a-b)(1-x^n)$$ whose integral over $[0,1]$ is $a-\frac{a-b}{n+1}$?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(\ln f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$, which is negative for any negative, increasing or positive, decreasing function. Among those, I don't think a linear function maximises the integral.

Comment: As said, any positive decreasing function satisfies the condition.  The supremum over all such functions would have the integral equal to $a$, but this isn't realized by a continuous function.  There is no answer.

Comment: Connect the points $(0,a)$, $(1-\epsilon, a-\epsilon)$ and $(1,b)$ with a smooth decreasing function and you get $\int f(x)\,dx$ almost $a$; there is no maximum.